# Dynamics - Web API filter by phone number in international fomat

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-dynamics

I'm using that URI to request contacts entity that matches a specific phone number:

```
/api/data/v8.1/contacts?$filter=telephone1 eq '"+ phoneNumber +"' or telephone2 eq '"+ phoneNumber +"' or telephone3 eq '"+ phoneNumber +"' or mobilephone eq '"+ phoneNumber +"' &$select=contactid,firstname,lastname,emailaddress1,birthdate"
```

Since the phone number is only digits: 0033648000000, it works. But when I try to do the same with an internationaly formatted phone number: +33648000000, it gives me no results even if 3 contacts are associated to the specified number. No error is displayed just like no contacts exists with that number. Some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the fact that the + sign is a special character in your url. You need to encode the phonenumber before appending it to the url:

```
/api/data/v8.1/contacts?$filter=telephone1 eq '"+ encodeURIComponent(phoneNumber) +"' or telephone2 eq '"+ encodeURIComponent(phoneNumber) +"' or telephone3 eq '"+ encodeURIComponent(phoneNumber) +"' or mobilephone eq '"+ encodeURIComponent(phoneNumber) +"' &$select=contactid,firstname,lastname,emailaddress1,birthdate"
```